# For a subgroup $H$ contained in the center of a finite group $G$ , $F(G/H)=F(G)/H$, where $F$ denotes Fitting subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For any group $G$, let $F(G)$ denote the Fitting subgroup. Now if $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$, then how to show that $F(G/H)=F(G)/H$  ?

Please help.

Comment: If you want help, then you should make some attempt to solve the problem yourself. To prove that two subgroups are equal, you need to prove that each of them is contained in the other. One of these two inclusions is easy, so do that one yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The advice of prof. Holt is very valid, but let me give you a small hint: put $F(G/H)=K/H$. Then $K/H$ is nilpotent and $H \subseteq Z(G)$ implies $H \subseteq Z(K)$. What does this say about $K/Z(K)$?